# Strapi GraphQL overwrites

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm trying to rewrite my GraphQL schema so that everything comes down from a "top query". For example, I have patient, locations, practices content types. but I want every query to start with `location { // rest of query` to prevent people from inspecting things that don't belong to them. To achieve this I have been adding schema.graphql to all my models to out

And then, I want to remove access to everything from practice and overwrite the findOne to exclude the parameters and just be `practice` where the controller will fill in the ID with the state of the current user.

```
module.exports = {
  query: `
    practice: Practice
  `,
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      practice: {
        description: 'Return the practice of the authenticated user',
        resolver: 'Practice.findMine'
      },
      practices: false
    }
  }
};
```

I can't make the previous code work because GraphQl with Internal error saying that I can only specify practice once. Even tho, it doesn't appear to be the case in the generated schema

```
type Query {
  practice: Practice
  files(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UploadFile]
  role(id: String!): UsersPermissionsRole

  """
  Retrieve all the existing roles. You can't apply filters on this query.
  """
  roles(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UsersPermissionsRole]
  user(id: String!): UsersPermissionsUser
  users(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [UsersPermissionsUser]
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the co-founders of Strapi. Can you try this? I think you need to disable the shadow CRUD feature for the Practice type.

```
module.exports = {
  definition: ``,
  query: `
    practice: Practice
  `,
  type: {
    Practice: false
  }
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      practice: {
        description: 'Return the practice of the authenticated user',
        resolver: 'Practice.findMine'
      },
      practices: false
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. That doesn’t seem to work at the time of the writing. But I will update to the current alpha (I’m one minor version behind) and double check

Comment: Tried the following code (fixing the missing `,` after type) but sadly it errors when trying to run strapi start with `Error: Resolver Query.practice must be object or function`